# HoverTool shows '???' in bokeh plot after a template render

Tags: python, hover, bokeh

I can't seem to get the HoverTool to show the info for the circle glyph after rendering the plot in this fashion(code below). The hovertool pops up but each of the tooltips show '???' instead of the info from the ColumnDataSource. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from jinja2 import Template

from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, BoxSelectTool,             GeoJSONDataSource
from bokeh.core.templates import CSS_RESOURCES, JS_RESOURCES
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
from bokeh.util.string import encode_utf8


source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
        desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
    )
)

hover = HoverTool(

    tooltips=[
        ("index", "$index"),
        ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
        ("desc", "@desc"),
    ]
)

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
       title="Mouse over the dots")

g1 = p.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source)

hover = HoverTool(
    renderers= [g1],
    tooltips=[
        ("index", "$index"),
        ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),
        ("desc", "@desc"),
    ]
)
p.add_tools(hover)

js_resources = JS_RESOURCES.render(
    js_raw=INLINE.js_raw,
    js_files=INLINE.js_files
)

css_resources = CSS_RESOURCES.render(
    css_raw=INLINE.css_raw,
    css_files=INLINE.css_files
)

script, div = components(p, INLINE)
template = Template('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Scatter Plots</title>
        {{ js_resources }}
        {{ css_resources }}
        {{ script }}
    </head>
    <body>
            {{ div }}
    </body>
</html>
''')
html = template.render(
    js_resources=js_resources,
    css_resources=css_resources,
    script=script,
    div=div
)

filename='toolTipPrac.html'
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Comment: example: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/tools.html#basic-tooltips

Comment: Your example worked for me on the `0.11.1` build.  What version of bokeh are you using? `bokeh.__version__`

Comment: It works on `master` as well.

Comment: That's odd because I am also on the 0.11.1 build. @bcollins

Comment: what version of Python/Browser/OS?  I'm on Python 3.5/Chrome/OSX

Comment: I got it to work on chrome. I was using the iceweasel browser which causes the ??? error apparently. Thanks for your help! @bcollins